# Select new records in SQL Server according to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database databaseOne with a table that has these columns:

company_name, account, data_uploaded_date

That table has 100000 records. I uploaded 5000 new rows of data today into the same table.

I need a query to check how many new company names are there which were not in databaseOne before?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where data_uploaded_date = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: ya getdate() frunction gives today's date

Comment: New company names means that the company added only today and was not added before. GetDate() function gives exact date and time, so try to use only the date part in your query and not the time part

Comment: exactly @GopeshSharma

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    company_name, account, data_uploaded_date 
FROM 
    Records
WHERE 
    CAST(data_uploaded_date as Date) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date) 
    AND company_name NOT IN (SELECT company_name 
                             FROM Records
                             WHERE CAST(data_uploaded_date as Date) < CAST(GETDATE() as Date))
```

Comment: According to the question, `databaseOne` is the **database** - not the table

Comment: thanks @marc_s thanks for the clarification. I know that it was database name but table name was not mentioned so i used that as table. Anyways corrected it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Count` with `Distinct` clause. And `IN` will won't work if containing `NULL` in it. So handled Null in Subquery which is passed to `NOT IN`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT company_name)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE company_name NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(company_name, '')
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE data_uploaded_date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        )
AND data_uploaded_date >=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```